# how can i get a value field from a store

Tags: extjs

I created a store with ExtJS 3.4 , here is my code :

```
var itiStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'getItiResultResult',
    fields: [
        {name: 'Arrival'},
        {name: 'ColumnsName'},
        {name: 'Error'},
        {name: 'Points', mapping: 'Points'},
        {name: 'La', mapping: 'Points.La'},
        {name: 'Lo', mapping: 'Points.Lo'},
        {name: 'Rows', mapping: 'Rows'},
        {name: "ChangeRowColor", mapping: 'Rows.ChangeRowColor'},
        {name: "CumDistance", mapping: 'Rows.CumDistance'},
        {name: "CumTime", mapping: 'Rows.CumTime'},
        {name: "Direction", mapping: 'Rows.Direction'},
        {name: "Distance", mapping: 'Rows.Distance'},
        {name: "La", mapping: 'Rows.La'},
        {name: "Lo", mapping: 'Rows.Lo'},
        {name: "RoadMap", mapping: 'Rows.RoadMap'},
        {name: "Step", mapping: 'Rows.Step'},
        {name: "Time", mapping: 'Rows.Time'},
        {name: "dCumDist", mapping: 'Rows.dCumDist'},
        {name: "dCumTime", mapping: 'Rows.dCumTime'},
        {name: 'Start'},
        {name: 'TotDistance'},
        {name: 'TotTime'}
    ]
});
```

i used to show my store :

`itiStore.loadData(Ext.decode(response.responseText), false);
                    console.log(JSON.parse(response.responseText));`

how can i get just the value of the field 'RoadMap' and recuperate it to show it apart.

Thank you guys in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Store contains many records so if you want it from one of them then:

```
var record = store.getAt(22); // or other way of getting a record
var roadMap = record.get('RoadMap');
```

If you want the store to contain only RoadMap then create another store with only that field and once you have decoded the JSON response load both stores with the decoded data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! but it doesn't work for me.. it give me this error : (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined) !! any ideas sir ?

Comment: what i want exactly is when i click in my boutton , the RoadMap appears in my application ! i calcule the itineraire by the way and i want that message (RoadMap) appears when i click in my boutton

Comment: First of all, store must be loaded, and second, I have used an arbitrary index `22` - you can use `0` to get the first record or any other index between `0` and `store.getCount() - 1`